# Which operating system takes more advantage of multi core cpus

Tags: 12.10, cpu, cpu-load

I want to know which one will benefit more from amd 8 (or in multi core setup in general) core setup windows or Ubuntu

or there will be no difference ??

thank you in advanced

Comment: It's not that much about the operating system. It's about the applications you're using (how many threads) and the way the scheduler (kernel) is able to handle this. Specific things like boot up time are a bit OS-specific, but your question is very broad.

Comment: so that means that It depends on devs to write the software that will support multi cores 
so that means any thing more then 2 cores is just a waste of core power ??
sad I was expecting something more better

Comment: Historically, software was written for single cores, as there were no multi-core setups. Parallel programming is something introduced "recently", and application should have this in the very roots of the code to support it. See also: [Wikipedia: Multithreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture)). It's very hard to get software to work 8 times as fast on 8 cores.

Comment: So Does this means I should get a dual core cpu and overclock absolute hell out of it that would make more seance then buying 8 core cpu

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. It heavily depends on what you're trying to do. A web server with a huge number of visitors perfectly capable of scaling across the cores, while running a single-threaded application isn't worth buying more cores. See this: [CPU Cores: The more the better?](http://superuser.com/questions/2489/cpu-cores-the-more-the-better)

Comment: Thank you for the information this is very useful but if I ask you a question what  os has more multi core optimized apps windows or Linux ???

Answer (score 5):

Both Ubuntu and Windows support 8 core CPUs.  I am running an Intel Core i7 with 4 cores and 4 extra threads and everything works.  I don't think any OS benefits "more".

[image]

Comment: Well, I think Ubuntu may benefit more because it uses less on it's own than Windows (at least this has been true in my experiences). Both will use them, but Ubuntu will use the CPUs better (ie less system junk taking up CPU power).

Comment: That could be.  I have noticed that Ubuntu tends to manage the CPU a little better than Windows does.

Answer (score 3):

(Seth you are wrong. an i7 has 4 cores  but 8 threads. 
the best i7 has a 6 cores and  12 threads.)
[specification best i7 specs](http://ark.intel.com/products/58664/Intel-Core-i7-980-Processor-12M-Cache-3_33-GHz-4_8-GTs-Intel-QPI)

AMD is the only one that has a 8 cores processor for desktops.
but AMD does not have Hyper Threading so it has also 8 threads
[best AMD FX processor specs](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Bulldozer/AMD-FX-Series%20FX-8350.html)

but I agree with your answer

> I don't think any OS benefits "more".

Comment: Ah, [you're](http://ark.intel.com/products/50067/Intel-Core-i7-2720QM-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_30-GHz) right, 4 cores 8 threads.